# invalid operands of types ‘const char [18]’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator

Tags: c++

*Im new to c++ so not sure where i miss out its* as only the description not allowing execute the code, hope able to help

```
    InventoryItem (char const *desc, double c, int u)
    {
     description = new char[strlen (desc) + 100];

      strcpy (description, desc);

   ~InventoryItem ()
    {
      delete[]description;
     }

      const char *getDescription () const
     {
    return description;
     }


     cout << setprecision (2) << fixed << showpoint;

      cout < "Item Description:" << stock.getDescription ()<< endl;
```

Comment: Typo: `cout < "Item Description:"` Should be `cout << "Item Description:"`. The former is trying to use the < operator on a string literal, resulting in the error message..

Comment: Take some time to describe your symptoms in more detail. What did you expect would happen? What actually happened? Was there an error message? What steps have you taken to [debug the problem](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `cout <` on the last line, where you should have `cout <<`.

I'm assuming the message said `operator <<`; C++ interpreted it as comparing `cout` to `"Item description:" << stock.getDescription() << endl`, but `"Item description:" << stock.getDescription()"` by itself doesn't make sense, so it gave an error.